# Spivak Prologue Question: Basic Properties of Numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra

**The Set Up**

I do not see how property 6 (P6) proves the assertion that $1 \neq 0$.

Spivak gives 6 properties of numbers before asserting this fact, followed by the statement that "there is no way it could possibly be proved on the basis of the other properties listed--these properties would all hold if there were only one number, namely, $0$."

> The Properties:
>
> (P1) If $a, b$, and $c$ are any numbers, then: $$a + (b + c) = (a + b) + c$$
>
> (P2) If $a$ is any number, then $$a + 0 = 0 + a = a$$
>
> (P3) For every number $a$, there is a number $-a$ such that $$a + (-a) = (-a) + a = 0$$
>
> (P4) If $a$ and $b$ are any numbers, then $$a + b = b + a$$
>
> (P5) If $a, b$, and $c$ are any numbers, then $$a \cdot (b \cdot c) = (a \cdot b) \cdot c$$
>
> (P6) If $a$ is any number, then $$a \cdot 1 = 1 \cdot a = a$$

**My Attempt**

I took the statement "these properties would all hold if there were only one number, namely, $0$" and input $0$ into all the properties. And yes, they held. Point: I was a skeptical about (P3) because of $-0$ but I went with it.

I then input $0$ into (P6) for a and as the equation stated, I ended up with $a$. It was at this point I felt stuck.

How does (P6) prove the assertion $1 \neq 0$ where the other properties could not? Could I please have a hint or critique on my thinking?

Thank you

Comment: I think you've misread Spivak. He says he has to list $0\neq 1$ separately because it does not follow from P1-P6. So P6 definitely does _not_ prove the assertion $0\neq 1$. Your calculation shows that the number system containing only $0$ satisfies P1-P6.

Comment: "I was a skeptical about (P3) because of -0."  The symbol $-$ here is used to denote that the number is the additive inverse of the number following the $-$ sign.  $-5$ is the additive inverse of $5$ for example.  That the $-$ sign is more commonly thought of as denoting the "negative" of the value that follows is because those concepts are so closely tied together, the negative of a number *is* the additive inverse of the number.  Perhaps it might be clearer to say $a+\text{inv}(a)=0$ and in this case $0+\text{inv}(0)=0$.  It should be clear the additive inverse of zero is itself.

Comment: @ziggurism You are correct, I did misread Spivak. The next property listed is "For every number a $\neq$ 0, there is a number a^-1 such that: a $\bullet$ a^-1 = a^-1 $\bullet$ a = 1. This property allows us to assert a 1 $\neq$ 0.

Answer (score 2):

P6 holds in the set with one element denoted both by $0 $ and $1 $ endowed with the only possible binary operation.  Therefore it cannot imply $0\neq1 $.

Answer (score 1):

You have observed that these properties are not sufficient to prove that $1 \neq 0$ because they have a model where there is only one element, which you call both $0$ and $1$ for these properties.  What you can say is that if there exists more than one element, then $1 \neq 0$.  If you assume there is an element $a$ distinct from $0$ but $1=0$, you can reach a contradiction by $$1 \cdot a=a\\0\cdot a=a\\(1-1)\cdot a=a\\0\cdot a - 0 \cdot a=a\\a-a=a\\0=a$$